# Continuous empty console input in Docker

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to run a Go console program in Docker. Everything works fine except the part where I take console input. The part that doesn't work is this:

```
func ListenTerminalInput() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    in := ""
    for in != "exit" {
        in, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
        in = strings.Replace(in, "\n", "", -1)
        in = strings.ToLower(in)
        switch in {
        case "exit":
            continue
        case "status":
            PrintStatus()
            continue
        case "servers":
            PrintServers()
            continue
        case "clients":
            PrintClients()
            continue
        case "help":
            PrintHelp()
            continue

        default:
            fmt.Println("Please make a valid choice. Type \"help\" for help.")
        }
    }
}
```

This code writes default statement to the console as fast as for loop executes. It only does this when it is execute in Docker container, if I execute it outside the container it works fine.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.9

MAINTAINER Hüseyin Atakan Çiçek

EXPOSE 56566
EXPOSE 56567

VOLUME /shared

WORKDIR /shared

CMD ["go", "run", "server.go"]m
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '3'
   services:

     server:
       image: goserver
       ports:
        - "56566:56566"
        - "56567:56567"
       volumes:
         - ./shared:/shared
```

Here is the output I get when I run it in Docker

[Docker execution console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7Dn.jpg)

Here is the output I get when I run it outside Docker

[Normal execution console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRJK0.jpg)

Comment: try to run docker container attach <container-name>

Comment: Don't ignore errors. There's an excellent chance the error you're ignoring would tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You were right it gives an EOF error.